# Azure graph query to get data

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-sdks, kusto-explorer

I'm writing azure graph query to extract the all vms, which include backup policy if associated it, if backup policy associated, need to extract the retention details of the backup. but I'm getting issue saying

> Table RecoveryServicesResources was referenced as right table 2 times, which exceeded the limit of 1. Please see https://aka.ms/resourcegraph-tables for help. (Code:DisallowedMaxNumberOfRemoteTables)

to get all backup polices and associated devices 
**Graph Query 1**

```
RecoveryServicesResources 
    | where type in~ ('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems')
    | where properties.backupManagementType == "AzureIaasVM"
    | extend vaultName = case(type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/')[1],'/')[0],type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],'--')
    | extend dataSourceType = case(type=~'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.backupManagementType,type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',properties.dataSourceSetInfo.datasourceType,'--')
    | extend friendlyName = properties.friendlyName
    | extend dsResourceGroup = split(split(properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceID, '/resourceGroups/')[1],'/')[0]
    | extend dsSubscription = split(split(properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceID, '/subscriptions/')[1],'/')[0]
    | extend primaryLocation = properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceLocation
    | extend policyName = case(type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.policyName, type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances', properties.policyInfo.name, '--')
    | extend protectionState = properties.currentProtectionState
    | extend vmProperties = properties
    | where protectionState in~ ('ConfiguringProtection','ProtectionConfigured','ConfiguringProtectionFailed','ProtectionStopped','SoftDeleted','ProtectionError')
    | project id, friendlyName, dataSourceType, dsResourceGroup, dsSubscription, vmProperties, vaultName, protectionState, policyName,primaryLocation
    | join kind = leftouter (
        RecoveryServicesResources
            | where type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies'
            | extend xvaultName = case(type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', split(split(id, 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', split(split(id, 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],'--')
            | extend datasourceType = case(type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', properties.backupManagementType,type == 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupPolicies',properties.datasourceTypes[0],'--')
            | extend policyID = id
            | extend dailyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.dailySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
            | extend daylyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.dailySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
            | extend DailyBackup = strcat("Daily, retention Duration ", daylyLTR, " ", dailyDurationType)
            | extend weeklyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
            | extend weeklyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
            | extend weeklyStartDate = split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
            | extend WeeklyBackup = strcat("Every ", weeklyStartDate, ", retention Duration ", weeklyLTR, " ", weeklyDurationType)
            | extend monthlyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
            | extend monthlyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
            | extend monthlyStartDayWeek =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
            | extend monthlyStartWeekMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.weeksOfTheMonth),'"')[1]
            | extend MonthlyBackup = strcat("Every ", monthlyStartDayWeek, " ", monthlyStartWeekMonth, " Week, retention Duration ", monthlyLTR, " " , monthlyDurationType)
            | extend yearDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
            | extend yearLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
            | extend yearlyStartDayWeek =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
            | extend yearlyStartWeekMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.weeksOfTheMonth),'"')[1]
            | extend yearlyStartMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.monthsOfYear),'"')[1]
            | extend YearlyBackup = strcat("Every month ", yearlyStartWeekMonth, " ", yearlyStartDayWeek, ", retention Duration ", yearLTR, " ", yearDurationType)
            | project resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.sourceResourceId)),policyID,policyName=name,DailyBackup,WeeklyBackup,MonthlyBackup,YearlyBackup,daylyLTR,weeklyLTR,monthlyLTR,yearLTR) on policyName
```

**2nd Query**

To get all Vm and if they have backup policy

```
Resources
| where type in~ ('microsoft.compute/virtualmachines','microsoft.classiccompute/virtualmachines') 
| extend resourceId=tolower(id) 
| extend sku = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku
| extend publisher = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.publisher
| extend offer = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer
| extend ostype = properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType
| extend hardwareType = properties.hardwareProfile
| join kind = leftouter ( 
    RecoveryServicesResources
    | where type in~ ("microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backupfabrics/protectioncontainers/protecteditems", "microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies")
    | where properties.backupManagementType == "AzureIaasVM"
    | extend backupItemid = id
    | extend isBackedUp = isnotempty(id)
    | extend policyName = case(type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.policyName, type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances', properties.policyInfo.name, '--')
    | extend vaultName = case(type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/')[1],'/')[0],type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],'--')
    | extend dataSourceType = case(type=~'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.backupManagementType,type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',properties.dataSourceSetInfo.datasourceType,'--')
    | project resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.sourceResourceId)), backupItemid, isBackedUp, policyName, vaultName, dataSourceType ) on resourceId
    | extend isProtected = isnotempty(backupItemid)
```

I try to combined them but getting following error,

**Combined Query**

```
Resources
| where type in~ ('microsoft.compute/virtualmachines','microsoft.classiccompute/virtualmachines') 
| extend resourceId=tolower(id) 
| extend sku = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.sku
| extend publisher = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.publisher
| extend offer = properties.storageProfile.imageReference.offer
| extend ostype = properties.storageProfile.osDisk.osType
| extend hardwareType = properties.hardwareProfile
| join kind = leftouter ( RecoveryServicesResources 
    | where type in~ ('Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems')
    | extend vaultName = case(type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.DataProtection/backupVaults/')[1],'/')[0],type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',split(split(id, '/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],'--')
    | extend dataSourceType = case(type=~'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.backupManagementType,type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances',properties.dataSourceSetInfo.datasourceType,'--')
    | extend friendlyName = properties.friendlyName
    | extend dsResourceGroup = split(split(properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceID, '/resourceGroups/')[1],'/')[0]
    | extend dsSubscription = split(split(properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceID, '/subscriptions/')[1],'/')[0]
    | extend primaryLocation = properties.dataSourceInfo.resourceLocation
    | extend policyName = case(type =~ 'Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems',properties.policyName, type =~ 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupInstances', properties.policyInfo.name, '--')
    | extend protectionState = properties.currentProtectionState
    | extend vmProperties = properties
    | where protectionState in~ ('ConfiguringProtection','ProtectionConfigured','ConfiguringProtectionFailed','ProtectionStopped','SoftDeleted','ProtectionError')
    | project id, friendlyName, dataSourceType, dsResourceGroup, dsSubscription, vmProperties, vaultName, protectionState, policyName,primaryLocation
    | join kind=leftouter (RecoveryServicesResources
    | where type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies'
    | extend xvaultName = case(type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', split(split(id, 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', split(split(id, 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/')[1],'/')[0],'--')
    | extend datasourceType = case(type == 'microsoft.recoveryservices/vaults/backuppolicies', properties.backupManagementType,type == 'microsoft.dataprotection/backupVaults/backupPolicies',properties.datasourceTypes[0],'--')
    | extend policyID = id
    | extend dailyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.dailySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
    | extend daylyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.dailySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
    | extend DailyBackup = strcat("Daily, retention Duration ", daylyLTR, " ", dailyDurationType)
    | extend weeklyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
    | extend weeklyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
    | extend weeklyStartDate = split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.weeklySchedule.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
    | extend WeeklyBackup = strcat("Every ", weeklyStartDate, ", retention Duration ", weeklyLTR, " ", weeklyDurationType)
    | extend monthlyDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
    | extend monthlyLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
    | extend monthlyStartDayWeek =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
    | extend monthlyStartWeekMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.monthlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.weeksOfTheMonth),'"')[1]
    | extend MonthlyBackup = strcat("Every ", monthlyStartDayWeek, " ", monthlyStartWeekMonth, " Week, retention Duration ", monthlyLTR, " " , monthlyDurationType)
    | extend yearDurationType = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('durationType','',replace('{','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[0])))))
    | extend yearLTR = replace('"','',replace(':','',replace('count','',replace('}','',tostring(split(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionDuration,',')[1])))))
    | extend yearlyStartDayWeek =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.daysOfTheWeek),'"')[1]
    | extend yearlyStartWeekMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.retentionScheduleWeekly.weeksOfTheMonth),'"')[1]
    | extend yearlyStartMonth =  split(tostring(properties.retentionPolicy.yearlySchedule.monthsOfYear),'"')[1]
    | extend YearlyBackup = strcat("Every month ", yearlyStartWeekMonth, " ", yearlyStartDayWeek, ", retention Duration ", yearLTR, " ", yearDurationType)
    | project resourceId = tolower(tostring(properties.sourceResourceId)),policyID,policyName=name,DailyBackup,WeeklyBackup,MonthlyBackup,YearlyBackup,daylyLTR,weeklyLTR,monthlyLTR,yearLTR) on policyName) on resourceId
```

**Error**

> Please provide below info when asking for support: timestamp = 2022-01-25T05:23:02.8691470Z, correlationId = e0cf5a44-aacb-4325-b6b1-edbdb44c2ac0. (Code:BadRequest)

Details:
Table RecoveryServicesResources was referenced as right table 2 times, which exceeded the limit of 1. Please see https://aka.ms/resourcegraph-tables for help. (Code:DisallowedMaxNumberOfRemoteTables)

Comment: quick update, I used the workaround to get the data. still interested on if it can do via azure graphs single query : https://github.com/shamera82/mysql